# Obter IP public do usuario do site

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicação-web, login, ip

Boa noite pessoal

Fiz uma aplicação Web com ASPNET e C#, e preciso obter o IP do usuário quando ele acessa o sistema.

Pesquisei se achei várias maneiras, mas sempre tenho este retorno: ::1

Segue abaixo do código usado:

```
Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_Host"].ToString());
```

Pesquisei aqui no StackOverflow e achei o código abaixo, mas me retorna o ip de onde a plicação está hospedada:

```
 public static string GetPublicIP()
    {
        string url = "http://checkip.dyndns.org";
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string response = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        string[] a = response.Split(':');
        string a2 = a[1].Substring(1);
        string[] a3 = a2.Split('<');
        string a4 = a3[0];
        return a4;
    }
```

Não sei mais o que fazer.

Então, galera. Como pego o ip público do usuário que acessou meu sistema?

Vlw..

Comment: Qual a versão do .net? Core ou "full framework"?

Comment: .NET 4.6.1, no WebForm

Comment: Esse retorno não porque você está rodando a aplicação localmente na sua máquina?

Comment: Você quer o IP de quem? Do usuário que está acessando a aplicação ou da máquina que está **rodando a aplicação** (seu servidor)?

Comment: Quero o IP de quem está acessando a aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter o IP público dos visitantes da sua aplicação, você pode usar as variáveis do servidor, que é o que você está fazendo mas não do jeito ideal.

A variável **REMOTE_HOST**, que é a que você está lendo, devolve o nome do host do cliente. Somente caso o servidor não tenha essa informação é que ele vai retornar o valor da variável **REMOTE_ADDR**, e essa sim contém o IP do host.

No entanto, alguns usuários podem estar acessando o seu site através de um proxy. Nesse caso, a variável REMOTE_HOST irá retornar o IP do servidor de proxy e não do cliente, que é o que queremos. Alguns servidores proxy enviam no cabeçalho da requisição o IP final do cliente, então é uma boa prática sempre checá-lo primeiro. O IP enviado, nesse caso, fica na variável **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR**.

O problema com essa variável é que ela pode ter mais de um endereço IP separado por vírgula. A lógica então fica:

1. Checar se a variável HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR existe
2. Se existir, devemos tentar quebrá-la por vírgula e retornar o primeiro endereço
3. Se não existir, retornar o valor da variável REMOTE_ADDR

O código fica mais ou menos assim:

```
private string GetIP()
{
    var ip = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ip))
    {
        var ips = ip.Split(',');

        return ips.First();
    }

    return Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

Quando você executar localmente, o IP será ::1 porque essa é a versão IPv6 do 127.0.0.1.